# Screen Resolution Change

Tags: plymouth

1. Recently I have installed the plymouth manager andI accidentally set my resolution to 1024X768-24 which does not fit my laptop exactly and everytime my system reboots an error message shows that error: `incorrect settings 1024X768-24`. I tried to change the resolution from the System Settings > Display but now only this 1024X768 is shown in the drop down. Kindly help me to reset the display properties to default.
2. Plymouth is not responding whenI click on it and i want to uninstall it kindly help me in that too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by using `sudo update-initramfs -u` and *fixplymouth script*

Read this article:
[*Install Plymouth Manager and Change Boot Screen in Ubuntu/Linux Mint*](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/install-plymouth-manager-and-change.html)

Comment: i tried the above answer and also followed the instructions in the link given. but no use... Kindly provide me what else can i do. I it also ok for me if i have to remove plymouth completely and reinstall it. For your info plymouth is not responding when i clicked and when i tried to remove it through ubuntu software center it says there are some dependencies and it cannot remove the software. Kindly help me out

Comment: yes, removing _plymouth_ it is very ineffective way. Since it is a boot script manager it's very depend on GRUB settings. Note, that in author repository [Plymouth Manager by Mario Guerriero](https://launchpad.net/~mefrio-g/+archive/plymouthmanager) not exist version compiled for 12.04. So, better for you is remove **Plymouth Manager** (but NOT **Plymouth**) and next Download SOURCE package and compile especial for your system.

Comment: though need to say it's very troublesome way ...

Comment: Look: [_Plymouth_](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth) is boot script manager. BUT **Plymouth Manager** it is an extra level manager over native manager ...