# Ugly Boot Screen after upgrading to 12.10

Tags: plymouth

Is there a way to change the ugly boot screen in 12.10?  It seems to have rolled back to that 8-bit blocky looking thing with tiny orange dots underneath.  It then breaks into process code under that, and it looks ghastly.

I've read some tutorials on getting Plymouth to do some neat things, but they were for older versions of Ubuntu.

I'm running a GeForce GTX 460 if that matters.  Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I've noticed/found a couple of things.  The upgrade on my laptop didn't do this.  It still uses the "normal" Ubuntu boot logo (using Plymouth, I assume).  So, something is off with my desktop.  And, I found and installed Super Boot Manager to see if that would help.  With that, I enabled Plymouth and added a new theme, but the machine still boots with the block-ugly logo.  Finally, I messed around with Grub on boot and added "nomodeset" after "quiet splash" and added it while deleting "quiet splash."  None of these solutions worked.  I'll keep hunting...

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and see if this line is present `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Comment: Yes, that line is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This http://www.namanb.com/2010/05/changing-bootup-resolution-plymouth-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html or this [Screen Resolution Change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161597/screen-resolution-change) may help you. Or even that: http://byobu.info/wiki/Changing_Plymouth_Resolution_in_Ubuntu ...
I used the fixplymouth (only) script and it worked for me. Hope it works for you too.
Plymouth manager wasn't available for ubuntu 12.10 yet ...

Comment: Lucas -- thank you so much for your answer.  You're a genius.  The first link did the charm!  Even in 12.10 the instructions worked just fine.  Turns out Grub had a lower resolution set and it needed adjusting.  Plymouth is working great and the Solar theme is gorgeous.  Hope this helps anyone else that is having similar issues.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Lucas The steps taken to solve the problem should be described in your answer.